# For logged in user, let them view a list of content they have created (front-end user)

Tags: views, users

I have a user called a creator who can create a 'skill' content type. When they are logged in, I want them to be able to view a list of the skills they have created. I am a beginner with drupal when it comes to users. What kind of settings would I need on my view so that the view showed only content by the logged in user. I know how to do this with custom code, but would be more convenient to do with views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Views UI, at the right, expand "Advanced". Next to "Relationships" click "Add" and select "Content: Author". Apply that and make sure the relationship is listed. Next, on the lower left is "Filter Criteria". Click "Add" and way down that list, select "User: Current". Click "yes" for "Logged in user" and you should only see your authored content.

Answer (score 1):

[image] Add the fields you want from your skill content type to fields and then simply add a relationship of **User: Author** and then  create a filter using field **User:current** and make sure you use setting logged on user